# JavaScript - get url params that are encoded URIs

Tags: javascript

How would I get the params in a URL that are encoded. Eg, in this URL, I want the 2 `cf=` and the 3 `cat=` values:

`search.php?st=advanced&qall=&qany=&cat%5B%5D=13&cat%5B%5D=14&cat%5B%5D=11&cf%5B%5D=16&cf%5B%5D=22`

I tried this and get null:

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
console.log(urlParams.get(`cat%5B%5D`)); // would like array [13,14,11]
console.log(urlParams.get(`cf%5B%5D`)); // would like array [16,22]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the other method of URLSearchParams object - wich is `getAll`:

```
console.log(urlParams.getAll(`cat%5B%5D`)); // will give you an array
```

you will get exactly what you wanted.

```
[13,14,11]
```

Answer (score 0):

[decodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) will decode a string that was uri encoded. Applying it in the OP case:

```js
const encodedUri = 'search.php?st=advanced&qall=&qany=&cat%5B%5D=13&cat%5B%5D=14&cat%5B%5D=11&cf%5B%5D=16&cf%5B%5D=22';

try {
  const decodedUri = decodeURI(encodedUri);
  console.log(decodedUri);
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```